# Prove or disprove that there are $n$ consecutive odd positive integers that are prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question:**

Prove or disprove that there are $n$ consecutive odd positive integers that are prime.

If my answer for the question above is correct, then a new question arises.

**My Attempt:**

Odd numbers consist of multiples of $5$. I think that address the question.

**New Question:**

Is there at most $3$ consecutive primes? If So how would someone tackle this?

Comment: There are plenty of odd numbers that are not a multiple of $5$, such as $31$, $47$, $999$. For solution, hint: If we take $3$ consecutive odd numbers, one of them is divisible by $3$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm just wondering if you are talking about the first question.

Comment: If you are not talking about the first question, that means, there are at most 3 odd consecutive integer which are prime, which is 3, 5, 7. For numbers $5$ or more, we will stumble upon an odd integer divisible by 3. Right?

Comment: Yes. that's right. The only $3$ consecutive are $3$, $5$, $7$,   which does not extend to $4$ consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. $17,19,21,23$ are $4$ consecutive odd numbers, none of which are divisible by $5$.  So the observation implies the maximum number of consecutive odd numbers that are primes is at most $4$ (and we should be careful: there is one prime that ends in $5$).

We know $3,5,7$ are three consecutive odd numbers that are primes.  So we next have one of two tasks:

- Find an example of four consecutive odd numbers that are primes; or
- Prove that no such example exists.

It's natural to consider the numbers $a,a+2,a+4$ modulo $3$ (to see if we find a factor of $3$).

- If $a \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, then ...?
- If $a \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, then ...?
- If $a \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, then ...?

Comment: AndreNicolas above said that if we take 3 consecutive odd numbers, one of them is divisible by 3. How does 17, 19, 21, 23 implies that there are 4 consecutive odd primes?

Comment: They are four consecutive odd numbers that are not multiples of $5$.  All I'm saying is that your attempt does not cover this case.  (They're not all prime.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** All primes except for $2$ and $3$ are of the form $6n\pm1$.